# Filtering on Kendo UI Grid Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

This is My Kendo Grid Post Method i want to perform filtring on Test Name in kendo grid i have tried using javscript but it didnt worked for me

Controller

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TestNotification(DataSourceRequest command)
    {
        EAssessmentNew.BAL.StudentBal studBal = new EAssessmentNew.BAL.StudentBal();
        int studentId = Convert.ToInt32(studBal.getStudentId(Session["sname"].ToString()));

        PageList<Test> TestDetails = studBal.testDetails(studentId, command.Page - 1, command.PageSize);

        var gridModel = new DataSourceResult
        {
            Data = TestDetails.Select(x =>
            {
                var TestModel = new Test();
                TestModel.Test_Id = x.Test_Id;
                TestModel.Test_Name = x.Test_Name;
                TestModel.Test_Date = x.Test_Date;
                TestModel.Start_Time = x.Start_Time;
                TestModel.End_Time = x.End_Time;
                return TestModel;
            }),
            Total = TestDetails.TotalCount,
        };
        return Json(gridModel);


    }

Kendo JQuery On View
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#test-grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("TestNotification", "Student"))",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: '',

                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    data: "Data",
                    total: "Total",
                    errors: "Errors"
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    display_kendoui_grid_error(e);
                    this.cancelChanges();
                },
                pageSize: 2,
                serverPaging: true,
                serverFiltering: true,
                serverSorting: true
            },
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: [10, 20, 30]
            },
            editable: {
                confirmation: false,
                mode: "inline"
            },
            scrollable: false,
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "Test_Name",
                    title: "Name",
                    filterable: true,

                    width: 10

                   // template: '<a title="Edit" href="/Admin/ViewCategoryDetails?categoryId=#=CategoryId#&categoryName=#=CategoryName#"><span class="k-icon k-edit"></span></a>'
                },
                {
                    field: "Test_Date",
                    title: "Test Date",

                    // template: '#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(Test_Date, "dd/MM/yyyy" )) #',
                    template:"#= kendo.toString(new Date(parseInt(Test_Date.substr(6))),'dd-MM-yyyy ')#",
                    width: 10
                },
                {
                    field: "Start_Time",
                    title: "Start Time",
                    width: 10,
                   // template: '<a onClick="return callConfirmationbox();" title="delete" href="/Admin/DeleteParentCategory?categoryId=#=CategoryId#"><span class="k-icon k-delete"></span></a>'

                },
                {
                    field: "End_Time",
                    title: "End Time",
                    width: 10,
                   // template: '<a title="Edit" href="/Admin/ViewCategoryDetails?categoryId=#=CategoryId#&categoryName=#=CategoryName#"><span class="k-icon k-edit"></span></a>'
                },
             {
                 field: "Test_Id",
                 title: "Action",
                 width: 10,
                 template: '<a  title="Apply" href="/Student/ApplyForTest?TestId=#=Test_Id#">Click To Apply</a>'

             }]
        });
    });
```

Above is my jquery for kendo grid how can i perform filtering on Test Name in grid i have tried using javascript i have a GetTestList method on controller which return me a list of test but its not working from filterin point of view any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can do Loal filtering easily if you are returning all the data doing flowing

```
$("#test-grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "json",
                            transport: {
                                read: {
                                    url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("TestNotification", "Student"))",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    data: '',
                                }
                            },
                            schema: {
                                data: "Data",
                                total: "Total",
                                errors: "Errors"
                            },
                            error: function (e) {
                                display_kendoui_grid_error(e);
                                this.cancelChanges();
                            },
                            pageSize: 2,
                            //serverPaging: true,
                            //serverFiltering: true,
                            //serverSorting: true
                        },
                        pageable: {
                            refresh: true,
                            pageSizes: [10, 20, 30]
                        },
                        editable: {
                            confirmation: false,
                            mode: "inline"
                        },
                        scrollable: false,
                        filterable: true,
                        sortable: true,
                        columns: [
                            {
                                field: "Test_Name",
                                title: "Name",
                                filterable: true,
                                width: 10
                            },
                            {
                                field: "Test_Date",
                                title: "Test Date",
                                width: 10
                            },
                            {
                                field: "Start_Time",
                                title: "Start Time",
                                width: 10,

                            },
                            {
                                field: "End_Time",
                                title: "End Time",
                                width: 10,
                            },
                         {
                             field: "Test_Id",
                             title: "Action",
                             width: 10,
                             template: '<a  title="Apply" href="/Student/ApplyForTest?TestId=#=Test_Id#">Click To Apply</a>'

                         }]
                    });
```

If you need to Do Server Paging and Filtering you should modify your  transport read also your action .

```
                                //serverPaging: true,
                                //serverFiltering: true,
                                //serverSorting: true
```

Above will call the read action when they are enabled and pass the page size , filter Object etc.. . so you should accept these paramters in your read action and return the filtered data or page data

i would write the read as a function so I can manage the parameters send to the action

```
transport: {
            read: function (options) {
// the option will have pagesize (eg:option.pagesize ) when paging
 // the option will have filter OBJ (eg:option.filter[]) when filtering 
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("TestNotification", "Student"))",,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {pageSize:option.pagesize }, // send the data accordingly (not sure exact syntax but its available in the option parameter)
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        options.success(result);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        options.error(result);
                    }
                });
            },
}
```

Comment: say that you have 50 record in your database and from your action if you return all 50 records there is no need for server filter or paging.

but if you return only 10 records out of 50 then you need server paging and filtering to filter or do paging for the all records you have. 

which option do you have for now?

Comment: supose write now i hv 4 records in my db i m showing 2 on one page and 2 on other and my issue is i want to set filter on test name so that user can easily find the desired results

Comment: you mean when the data is loaded you need to filter the test name or activate filter for that column ?

Comment: yes now u got me when data is loaded in the grid i want to put filter beside test name so i can filter accordingly

Comment: ok cool , you don't need serverPaging ,serverFiltering or serverSorting . as i have done put "filterable:true" before columns. don't you need filtering for other columns ? if not add "filterable: false" for other columns

Comment: i have added  filterable true for test name still it does not provide me filtering on test name

Comment: post your updated code and your read return Json. i will provide you a js fiddler example

Comment: @user3831519 do not update my code , i need you to update yours

Comment: i do not see that you have updated your code according to my example . you need to remove serverPaging: true,serverFiltering: true,serverSorting: true and add filterable: true,sortable: true as my example for local filtering . and i don't see the Json result to provide you a fiddle example

Comment: var gridModel = new DataSourceResult
        {
            Data = TestDetails.Select(x =>
            {
                var TestModel = new Test();
                TestModel.Test_Id = x.Test_Id;
                TestModel.Test_Name = x.Test_Name;
                TestModel.Test_Date = x.Test_Date;
                TestModel.Start_Time = x.Start_Time;
                TestModel.End_Time = x.End_Time;
                return TestModel;
            }),
            Total = TestDetails.TotalCount,
        };
        return Json(gridModel);

Comment: this is my json result i mreturning to grid

Comment: that's not a Json result friend , capture it from the browser network response . that's the object send from your action i need the result after  Json(gridModel) is executed